Finding marginal propensity to consume

For the first part of my question:
I've calculated my IS (Biens et services = Goods and services) and LM (Monnaie = Money) equations and equilibrium output and interest rate for which I obtained:
Y = 290 - 500i as my LM eqn
Y= 120 + 1200i as my LM eqn
i = 0.1
Y = 240.
Up to here my answers are correct.
For the second part of my question the following is stated : Suppose the government of this closed economy decides to implement an expansionary fiscal policy to achieve a production level of 360. By how much must public spending be increased to achieve this goal?
I proceeded by saying delta Y/ delta G = (360-240)/delta G = fiscal multiplier = 1/1-MPC. From my consumption function I have that c = 0.5. Thus, after calculation my change in G is equal to 60.
However, the answer is G changes by 85.
Could someone please tell me where I  went wrong ?
